# Boolean operators and Conditions

Tags: python-3.x, conditional-statements, boolean-operations

I'm struggling to get my code running perfectly.

Question:

Write a function should_shutdown(battery_level, time_on) which returns True if the battery level is less than 4.8 except when the time_on is less than 60. If that is not the case, the function returns True only if the battery level is less than 4.7.  In all other situations the function returns False.

My code:

```
def should_shutdown(battery_level,time_on):
    if battery_level and time_on < 60:
        return False
    elif battery_level < 4.8:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

It works just fine, except when i test it with the following:

```
ans = should_shutdown(4.69, 50)
print(ans)
```

It returns `False`, but the correct answer should be `True`.

Other Tests:

- should_shutdown(5, 10)
  Expected: False
  Got: False
- should_shutdown(4.74, 90)
  Expected: True
  Got: True
- should_shutdown(4.74, 50)
  Expected: False
  Got: False
- should_shutdown(4.7, 50)
  Expected: False
  Got: False

**- should_shutdown(4.69, 50)
Expected: True
Got: False**

- should_shutdown(4.75, 60)
  Expected: True
  Got: True
- should_shutdown(4.75, 59)
  Expected: False
  Got: False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def should_shutdown(battery_level, time_on):
    if battery_level < 4.8:
        if time_on < 60:
            return False
        else:
            return True
    else:
        if battery_level < 4.7:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Your problem lies in the first if-statement:

```
if battery_level and time_on < 60:
```

This is the same as

```
if battery_level!=0 and time_on<60:
```

This is because in python, any number that is not `0` evaluates to `True`. Perhaps you meant:

```
if battery_level<4.8 and time_on < 60:
```

Comment: Ur code is giving me the same results as i have with mine.
it is not passing this:

`ans = should_shutdown(4.69, 50)

print(ans)`
It's returning `False`, not `True`.

Comment: `returns True if the battery level is less than 4.8 except when the time_on is less than 60`. At `battery_level=4.69` and `time_on=50`, we are in the part of the specification that says `except when the time_on is less than 60`, which means `return False`. So this output is correct

Comment: Yes, but i think ur missing the part where it says: _returns True only if the battery level is less than 4.7_.

Comment: It's still not passing: `should_shutdown(4.69, 50)`. it's returning `False`. - @inspectorG4dget

Comment: @Moh'dH: At this point, I'm going to say that the question is ambiguous. Please edit your post with sample inputs and expected outputs, with clear explanations as to how they demonstrate the requirements of the question. My code does what I understand the question to ask. Since that is clearly wrong, I need clarificaiton

Comment: from the question, i understand that whenever battery_level is < 4.7, it will return True, regardless of time_on's value. I've added some testing at the bottom of the question.